# ElasticSearch autocomplete doesn't work with the middle words

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Using python elasticsearch-dsl:

```
class Record(Document):
    tags = Keyword()
    tags_suggest = Completion(preserve_position_increments=False)

    def clean(self):
        self.tags_suggest = {
            "input": self.tags
        }

    class Index:
        name = 'my-index'
        settings = {
            "number_of_shards": 2,
        }
```

When I index

```
r1 = Record(tags=['my favourite tag', 'my hated tag'])
r2 = Record(tags=['my good tag', 'my bad tag'])
```

And when I try to use autocomplete with the word in the middle:

```
dsl = Record.search()

dsl = dsl.suggest("auto_complete", "favo", completion={"field": "tags_suggest"})
search_response = dsl.execute()

for option in search_response.suggest.auto_complete[0].options:
    print(option.to_dict())
```

It won't return anything, but it will when I search "my favo". Any good practices to fix that (make it return 'my favourite tag' when I request suggestions for "favo")?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Mapping**

Search in Elasticsearch, Is also depends on how you are indexing your data. I would suggest to have look on index mapping with the below query:

```sh
curl -X GET "elasticsearch.url:port/index_name/_mapping?pretty"
```

You need to check how data is being inserted like is it using any analyzer or tokeninzer to save data. If you have not specified any analyzer elasticsearch default uses [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). It will produce the terms accordingly.

As per your use case you need to apply analyzer, tokens & filters. Here is the one Example where i have to use like query and implemented [ngram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html).

**Solution**

As i can see you are using [suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html), The suggest feature suggests similar looking terms based on a provided text by using a suggester.

If you want to achieve autocomplete, I would suggest to use [search as you type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html).

I tried to reproduce your use case and below is something which worked for me.

1. **Create Index**

```sh
PUT /test1?pretty
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. **Indexing data**

```sh
POST test1/_doc?pretty
{
  "tags":"my favourite tag"
}

POST test1/_doc?pretty
{
  "tags":"my hated tag"
}

POST test1/_doc?pretty
{
  "tags":"my good tag"
}

POST test1/_doc?pretty
{
  "tags":"my bad tag"
}
```

3. **Query with your keyword**

```sh
GET /test1/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "my",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "tags",
        "tags._2gram",
        "tags._3gram"
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET /test1/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "bad",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "tags",
        "tags._2gram",
        "tags._3gram"
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET /test1/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "fav",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "tags",
        "tags._2gram",
        "tags._3gram"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Greetings. I already tried the concept you suggested, the problem with it is that completion suggester can return unique values in the field themselves that match the pattern we search ("my favo"), and in your case your search returns documents, not field values.

This could be acceptable, if "tags" was only one string, not an array of strings. But since the thing that is needed is to perform search in the index of "Records" between unique "tags", not "records", it won't help.

Comment: Considering you mentioned analyzers: I also tried adding shingle analyzer for Complete Suggester, but it didn't seem to take effect.


`english_shingles = analyzer(
    "english",
    tokenizer="whitespace",
    filter=["shingle"],
)`

`tags_suggest = Completion(analyzer=english_shingle, preserve_position_increments=False)`

Comment: @JediKnight can you give me example with input and output. I can find you best approach on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by setting `preserve_position_increments` parameter to `false` in your mappings.

```
"tags_completion": {
  "type": "completion",
  "analyzer": "simple",
  "preserve_separators": false,
  "preserve_position_increments": false,
  "max_input_length": 50
}
```

You can query it in console like this:

```
GET /_search
{
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggester": {
      "prefix": "favou",
      "completion": {
        "field": "tags_completion",
        "skip_duplicates": true,
        "fuzzy": {
          "fuzziness": 1
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
}
```